# Can a category's partial monoid of arrows be completed to a total monoid?

Tags: ct.category-theory

Categories can be presented in the language of arrows only, without reference to objects (as discussed, say, here: [Categories presented with Arrows only, no objects: partial monoids](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76083/categories-presented-with-arrows-only-no-objects-partial-monoids)), and this is a partial monoid. Next question appears naturally - can such a partial monoid be completed up to a ***total*** monoid?

My first impulse is to add a new arrow "$\oslash$" ("null"), and set $g \circ f = \oslash$,  for any two arrows $f, g$, such that $dom(g) \ne codom(f)$, then extend the composition operation in such a manner that $h \circ \oslash = \oslash$ and $\oslash \circ h = \oslash$, for any $h$. Also, I would discurd all identities and use instead only one arrow $1$, such that $h \circ$ $1 = 1$ and $1$ $\circ$ $h = h$, for any $h$. Am I missing something, or this is the required completion to a monoid?

If this is a completion to a monoid, and it contains an element which behaves like a "zero" in a ring, then next question appears naturally: cannot this monoid be extended to a ring?

Has anybody encountered in literatue something similar to this?

Comment: See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+algebra.

Comment: You can add a zero to get a semigroup. To get a monoid you then add a one. You can't remove however the identities that exist.

Comment: In semigroup theory the semigroup you get by adding a zero is sometimes called the consolidation of the category. It is not natural to add the identity so you should really say partial semigroup.

Comment: See http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404987901083 for a place where this is used (even with the adjoined identity).